# Issue with Custom Error template in CakePHP 4.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to know what is the right method to render the custom error templates for missingController, missingTemplate exceptions in 4.x. I have an ErrorController that extends the AppController and a custom AppExceptionRenderer that goes in the src/Error/AppExceptionRenderer which was working in 3.x. After migrating to 4.0, all error and exceptions are rendering either error400 or error500 pages only. I can see the error request reaching the ErrorController/initialize(), but not reaching the ErrorController beforefilter (which was going through the beforefilter in 3.x).

I am using Authentication, Authorization and RequestAuthorization Middlewares in my Application.php. Here is the sample code to illustrate the issue.

src/Application/middleware()

```
$middlewareQueue
            ....
            ->add(new AuthenticationMiddleware($this))
            ->add(new AuthorizationMiddleware($this, [
                    'requireAuthorizationCheck' => true,
                    'unauthorizedHandler' => [
                        'className' => 'CustomRedirect',
                        'url' => '/pages/permission',
                        'exceptions' => [
                            'MissingIdentityException' => 'Authorization\Exception\MissingIdentityException',
                            'ForbiddenException' => 'Authorization\Exception\ForbiddenException'
                        ],
                    ],
                ]))
            ->add(new RequestAuthorizationMiddleware());
```

I have implemented the RequestPolicy with the canAccess function.

RequestPolicy/canAccess()

```
public function canAccess($identity, ServerRequest $request)
{
    $unauthenticatedActions = $request->getAttribute('authentication')->getConfig('unauthenticatedActions');
    if (in_array($request->getParam('action'), $unauthenticatedActions, true)) { 
        return true;
    }
    else if(!empty($identity)){
        //check based on actions and user roles

        $userRole = $identity->role;
        $userStatus = $identity->status;
        $accountType = $identity->accountsubType;
        $action = $request->getParam('action');
        $controller = $request->getParam('controller');

        switch ($controller) {

            case 'Users':
                  if($userRole === 'ADMIN' && $userStatus === 'ACTIVE'){
                     return true;
                  }elseif($action === 'aaa'){
                     ...
                  }
                  break;
            ....
            default:
                //if none of the Controller names matches
                return true;
    }
}
```

I have 3 custom templates for missingController, missingTemplate and missingAction exceptions along with the error400 and error500 templates in my templates/Error folder.

[image]

The issue now is, if the request Controller/Action is not found, it redirects to the Error500 page in 4.0. It used to go to the missingController/missingAction pages respectively in 3.x. What should I do to properly render my missingController template etc. instead of error500 in 4.x? At the same time, is it possible that I can pass these error requests through my ErrorController beforefilter to do some logging?

/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php

```
namespace App\Error;

use Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Http\Session;

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer
{
    public function render(): ResponseInterface
    {    
        //setting the custom variables
        ...
        ...
        return parent::render();
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Error: [Cake\Controller\Exception\MissingActionException] Action UsersController::random() could not be found, or is not accessible. in ../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php on line 500
Exception Attributes: array (
  'controller' => 'UsersController',
  'action' => 'random',
  'prefix' => '',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
Stack Trace:
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:77
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php:229
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77
- .../vendor/cakephp/authorization/src/Middleware/RequestAuthorizationMiddleware.php:102
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- .../vendor/cakephp/authorization/src/Middleware/AuthorizationMiddleware.php:129
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- .../vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php:124
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/BodyParserMiddleware.php:159
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php:160
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php:68
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:119
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/EncryptedCookieMiddleware.php:93
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- .../vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Middleware/DebugKitMiddleware.php:60
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58
- .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php:90
- .../webroot/index.php:91

Request URL: /users/random
```

Comment: For starters those templates are only used when debug mode is enabled (it was the same in 3.x though).

Comment: I have got the custom error pages working by removing the parent::beforeRender($event); from my ErrorController/beforeRender. I have some Authentication checking in the AppController/beforeRender which might have been causing the issue. I had to also remove the parent::initialize(); from the ErrorController initialize to get the ErrorController/beforeFilter working.